# Django 1.6 AbstractUser m2m models validation error

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models

I don't have errors with Django 1.5.4 (stable), but when I was testing my application on Django 1.6 beta 4 from official tar.gz I got error with validation models on startup.

---

***models.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, User

class ShopUser(AbstractUser):
    model_car = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_car = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)

    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This is **manage.py runserver** console log:

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x2d941b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 97, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 312, in validate
    raise CommandError("One or more models did not validate:\n%s" % error_text)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:

adminka.shopuser: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
adminka.shopuser: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
```

- python -c "import django;print django.get_version()"
  **1.6b4**

### What need to do for solve this problem?

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6b4/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L448), `User` inherits from `AbstractUser`. That is the reason it clashes ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must declare **AUTH_USER_MODEL** on your **settings.py**. In your case:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.ShopUser'
```

Comment: Its not properly documented that this setting is required even when you are using AbstractUser and not AbstractBaseUser. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19049#no2

Answer (score 1):

For me this was fixed in Django 1.6.5 by changing this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

to this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    pass
```

No other changes needed in Django 1.6.5. @Stormlifter's suggestion has merit but I am using this CustomUser with this stuff for OAuth2 via python-social-auth:

```
$ pip freeze
Django==1.6.5
Markdown==2.4.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
PyJWT==0.2.1
South==1.0
basicauth==0.2
boto==2.28.0
django-filter==0.7
django-guardian==1.2.0
django-storages==1.1.8
djangorestframework==2.3.14
httplib2==0.9
oauth2==1.5.211
oauthlib==0.6.3
python-memcached==1.53
python-oauth2==0.7.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.1
requests==2.4.1
requests-oauthlib==0.4.1
shortuuid==0.4.2
six==1.7.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

My new CustomUser will be doing more than the default user and does need to be the `AUTH_USER_MODEL='myapp.CustomUser'` in `settings.py` as @jordiburgos suggested.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You want to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` not from `AbstractUser`.

However, it looks like you just want to store some additional information for users, I wouldn't recommend using a custom user model for this. Just use relationships.

```
class ShopUser(models.Model):
    model_car = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_car = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

You could make that a ForeignKey if you need Multiple ShopUser's to relate to a single user, but I think OneToOne makes the most sense.

As told by Django Documents:

[Specifying a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

[AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser)

Comment: Custom user model seems like a suitable way to do this, why do you not want to recommend it?

Comment: Well since not all users would be shop users, and in general that data may not be needed every time a user is called down so forming a relationship improved the organization of the data, it's not necessary and everyone should design their database for their application.